# Command line filtering log by date and legitimate requests in Analog

Tags: analytics, linux

Is there any way to get Analog to report the number of hits per day and the number of different IP addresses that are *from legitimate readers*? I define "legitimate" readers as accesses that (1) not robots and (2) do not generate 404 errors. In other words I need Analog to go through my log file, ignore IP addresses that access robots.txt and/or generate 404 errors, then count up how many unique IP addresses there are per day from the Linux command line. So, the output would be something like:

```
2020-03-01 523
2020-03-02 479
2020-03-03 1,203
2020-03-04 745
...
etc.
```

Is there any way to get Analog to do this?

Comment: Why would legitimate users not get 404 errors?    Why do you need Analog to do this, as opposed to any other command line tool?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I am open to using a different tool if there is an easy way to do it with a different tool. It is possible for a legitimate request to have a 404 but it is very rare. 99.9% of my 404 errors are caused by automated hacking systems trying to beak into the server. I don't care about the tiny percentage of 404s that for some miscellaneous reason might be legitimate.

Comment: hacking attempts don't usually hit 200 OK, either.   I'd suggest you should just ignore 404 errors entirely for this purpose.   Just because a user hit a 404 page, it shouldn't disqualify their legit requests.   But a client that hits only 404 pages shouldn't be counted as legit either.